Is there a difference between "Working" and "I'm working"?

What are you doing?
Working/I'm working

Is there a difference between "working" and "I'm working"?

In what context?  "Working" in isolation is not a complete sentence and would derive meaning from its context.

As an answer to "What are you doing?", "Working" is the shortest answer you could give, and would sound rude unless you were talking to someone you knew very well. "I'm working" is a little less abrupt.

Just as in Chinese one can answer a question like 想不想? (Do you want it?) with 想 (want) to mean, “Yes, I do want it,” one way to answer the question What are you [or is she or were they or …] doing? is with a bare present participle.

If your question here is about possible differences in two ways of answering the query What are you doing? (or whatever your purpose is) I suggest you edit your post—and its title—to make that clear. Otherwise it may get closed due to unclarity.

Although it is possible to reply with the single word "working", you need to be aware that this could be seen as impolite or abrupt and could give the wrong impression when talking to friends or colleagues. In some contexts it could imply that you are annoyed by the question or by the person asking it.

Thank you everybody!

"Working" is not a sentence.
In the same way, "a pencil" is not a sentence.  But when you are asked a question, "What is it?" you might reply, "A pencil". You can also reply "It's a pencil".
"It's a pencil" is a clause and sentence. There is a subject and a verb. In the same way, you can reply to the question "What are you doing?" with the sentence "I'm working" or with the word "working".
This kind of shortening of sentences to single words or short phrases is common in all natural languages that I am aware of, including Chinese.

Thank you! That was Very helpful.

Both are semantically identical, but the shorter one has been subjected to answer ellipsis, where you don't repeat in an answer things that were stated or implied in the question. The words in brackets were omitted, like this:

[I'm] working

